# Set smooth CSS animation to the variables

Tags: css, variables, animation, colors

I tried to add an animation to where I defined some colors as variables on CSS, but it is not smooth!!

if I add a similar animation (for example on a p tag color) it works fine and the color does change smoothly but, for changing variables I have a problem.

for example:

```css
body{
    --navColor1: #a1d0ff;
    --navColor2: #f088b0;
    --navColor3: #8cff8c;
    --navColor4: #fff676;
    --navColor5: #4d4d4d;
    --navColor6: #ff5555;
    --navColor7: #4d4fff;
    --navColor8: #9a4dff;
    --navColor9: #000000;
    animation: 3s infinite .1s pulse;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        --navColor1: #a1d0ff;
        --navColor2: #f088b0;
        --navColor3: #8cff8c;
        --navColor4: #fff676;
        --navColor5: #4d4d4d;
        --navColor6: #ff5555;
        --navColor7: #4d4fff;
        --navColor8: #9a4dff;
        --navColor9: #000000;
    }
    25% {
        --navColor1: #f088b0;
        --navColor2: #a1d0ff;
        --navColor3: #fff676;
        --navColor4: #8cff8c;
        --navColor5: #ff5555;
        --navColor6: #4d4d4d;
        --navColor7: #9a4dff;
        --navColor8: #4d4fff;
        --navColor9: #000000;
    }
    50% {
        --navColor1: #f088b0;
        --navColor2: #a1d0ff;
        --navColor3: #9a4dff;
        --navColor4: #8cff8c;
        --navColor5: #4d4fff;
        --navColor6: #ff5555;
        --navColor7: #000000;
        --navColor8: #fff676;
        --navColor9: #4d4d4d;
    }
    75% {
        --navColor1: #9a4dff;
        --navColor2: #000000;
        --navColor3: #8cff8c;
        --navColor4: #ff5555;
        --navColor5: #4d4d4d;
        --navColor6: #fff676;
        --navColor7: #4d4fff;
        --navColor8: #f088b0;
        --navColor9: #a1d0ff;
    }
    100% {
        --navColor1: #ff5555;
        --navColor2: #fff676;
        --navColor3: #8cff8c;
        --navColor4: #f088b0;
        --navColor5: #4d4d4d;
        --navColor6: #4d4fff;
        --navColor7: #9a4dff;
        --navColor8: #a1d0ff;
        --navColor9: #000000;
    }
}

.elem {
    padding: 10px;
}

.elem1 {
    background-color: var(--navColor1);
}

.elem2 {
    background-color: var(--navColor2);
}

.elem3 {
    background-color: var(--navColor3);
}

.elem4 {
    background-color: var(--navColor4);
}

.elem5 {
    background-color: var(--navColor5);
}

.elem6 {
    background-color: var(--navColor6);
}

.elem7 {
    background-color: var(--navColor7);
}

.elem8 {
    background-color: var(--navColor8);
}

.elem9 {
    background-color: var(--navColor9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="elem elem1">1</div>
    <div class="elem elem2">2</div>
    <div class="elem elem3">3</div>
    <div class="elem elem4">4</div>
    <div class="elem elem5">5</div>
    <div class="elem elem6">6</div>
    <div class="elem elem7">7</div>
    <div class="elem elem8">8</div>
    <div class="elem elem9">9</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and the result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2X1T.gif)

as you see the color changes suddenly.

is it possible to make it smoother??

or the whole idea is wrong!!

NOBODY?!

Comment: Can you give us working code snippet so we can work with something?

Comment: I added s code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we think of the animation from the computer's point of view, when it starts it has a specific color for the background for an element. Defined as a CSS variable. It 'looks forward' to see what comes next and finds that the element's background is to stay the same color, because at that time (0%) the variable is fixed. So it starts the animation, the color stays the same, then it gets to 25%, sees the color has changed and changes it etc.

You can get the desired effect by doing things the other way round.

Give each element a set of colors, each being one you want it to reach at a keyframe, then set the animation to move between these colors. The computer can tell what color is coming next, and does the appropriate mix to get to it.

Note: in order to get a smooth transition back to the start color we need the final color stop to be that color so the animation has an extra step in it and I increased the time to 4s just as an example. Also this snippet does just the first 2 elements to give you the idea. The other elements need their colors defining and the animation set in the same way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
       background-color: var(--col1);
    }
    20% {
       background-color: var(--col2);
    }
    40% {
       background-color: var(--col3);
    }
    60% {
       background-color: var(--col4);
    }
    80% {
       background-color: var(--col5);
    }
    100% {
       background-color: var(--col1); /* to get a smooth transition back to the original color */
    }
}

.elem {
    padding: 10px;
    animation: pulse 4s infinite;
    ranimation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.elem1 {
    --col1: #a1d0ff;
    --col2: #f088b0;
    --col3: #f088b0;
    --col4: #9a4dff;
    --col5: #a1d0ff; /* the last color needs to be the same as the first to get a smooth transition at the end of each cycle */
}

.elem2 {
    --col1: #f088b0;
    --col2: #a1d0ff;
    --col3: #000000;
    --col4: #fff676;
    --col5: #f088b0; /* the last color needs to be the same as the first to get a smooth transition at the end of each cycle */

}

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="elem elem1">1</div>
    <div class="elem elem2">2</div>

</body>

</html>
```